# R - alternative to using sqldf for subsetting

Tags: r, sqldf

> ID <- c(1:7)
>
> Q1 <- c(12,12,15,14,11,101,1009)
>
> df4 <- data.frame(ID,Q1)
>
> View(df4)

```
ID | Q
1 | 12
2 | 12
3 | 15
4 | 14
5 | 11
6 | 101
7 | 1009
```

With sqldf I could get a subset where records have Q value of 12,101 or 1009

> dt4 <- as.data.table(df4) #to convert df4 to table
>
> df5 <- sqldf("select* from dt4 where Q1 in (12,101,1009)")
>
> View(df5)

```
ID | Q
1 | 12
2 | 12
6 | 101
7 | 1009
```

How can I achieve same without using sqldf?

Answer (score 1):

```
df4[which(df4$Q1 %in% c(12, 101, 1009)),]
```

or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df4 %>% filter(Q1 %in% c(12, 101, 1009))
```